# tkinter checkbutton different image

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, ttk

I want a tkinter checkbutton that basically has my own images for on and off, so not the default checkbutton. I've searched the internet for a solution, but couldn't find anything. I'm thinking it might be possible with ttk styling, but i'm not sure how

tried changing the selectimage option in the checkbutton, which did absolutely nothing

edit:
turning indicatoron to false, then changing image and selectimage works

Comment: ***"not the default checkbutton"***: Try `indicatoron=False`. [Edit] your question and show your attemp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `image` option for the unselected state, and the `selectimage` option for the selected state. You also need to set `indicatoron` to `False` so that tkinter doesn't show the default indicator.

Here is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

on_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
off_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
on_image.put(("green",), to=(0, 0, 23,23))
off_image.put(("red",), to=(24, 0, 47, 23))

var1 = tk.IntVar(value=1)
var2 = tk.IntVar(value=0)
cb1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, image=off_image, selectimage=on_image, indicatoron=False,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var1)
cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, image=off_image, selectimage=on_image, indicatoron=False,
                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=var2)

cb1.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
cb2.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The `ttk.Checkbutton` widget has fewer options than the `tk.Checkbutton` widget. E.g. the options `selectimage` and `indicatoron` options are not available.

To achieve the same result as shown in the [answer by @ByranOakley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560611/5722359), the following was done:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root['background'] = 'white'  # for linux distro

# Remove the indicator from a customised TCheckbutton style layout
s = ttk.Style()
s.layout('no_indicatoron.TCheckbutton',
         [('Checkbutton.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
             # ('Checkbutton.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
             ('Checkbutton.focus', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'w',
                                    'children':
                                    [('Checkbutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]
         )

on_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
off_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
on_image.put(("green",), to=(0, 0, 23, 23))
off_image.put(("red",), to=(24, 0, 47, 23))

var1 = tk.IntVar(value=1)
var2 = tk.IntVar(value=0)


# Define functions to check Checkbutton state to show the corrsponding image.
def cb1_state():
    if cb1.instate(['!disabled', 'selected']):
        cb1['image'] = on_image
        print(f'cb1-on_image {var1.get()}')
    else:
        cb1['image'] = off_image
        print(f'cb1-off_image {var2.get()}')
    print()


def cb2_state():
    if cb2.instate(['!disabled', 'selected']):
        cb2['image'] = on_image
        print(f'cb2-on_image {var2.get()}')
    else:
        cb2['image'] = off_image
        print(f'cb2-off_image {var2.get()}')
    print()


# Use the customised style and functions
cb1 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, image=off_image, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                      variable=var1, style='no_indicatoron.TCheckbutton',
                      command=cb1_state)
cb2 = ttk.Checkbutton(root, image=off_image, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                      variable=var2, style='no_indicatoron.TCheckbutton',
                      command=cb2_state)

cb1.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
cb2.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Thank you! This worked great for my use case with a little adaptation.