# Checkbutton is not clickable after adding an image to it

Tags: python, image, tkinter, checkbox

I started working with tkinter recently and I have the following problem, I need to make the check box bigger but that is only possible with adding an image. The problem is that whenever I add an image to a button it becomes unclickable and the image is not displayed, here is my source code (part of a bigger project). My goal is to display some information and let the user decide which option he gets to keep using the check button. Any help is appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar as tkc
LARGE_FONT = ("HELVETICA", 32, 'bold')
NORMAL_FONT = ("calibri", 18)
class ConstituireDosar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.update_idletasks()
        # self.dosar = dosar
        self.controller = controller

        self.minsize(651, 569)
        # self.maxsize(651, 569)

        frame_titlu = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_titlu.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        frame_continut = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_continut.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "w")
        frame_acte = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_acte.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
      
        titlu = tk.Label(frame_titlu, font = LARGE_FONT, text = "Constituire Dosar")
        titlu.grid(row = 0 , column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 15)
        data_emiterii = tk.Label(frame_continut, font = NORMAL_FONT,text = "Data emiterii documentului:")
        data_emiterii.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = "w")
        self.cal = tkc.DateEntry(frame_continut, date_pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY", width = 20)
        self.cal.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = "w")
        debitori_label = tk.Label(frame_continut, font = NORMAL_FONT, text = "Selecteaza debitorii.")
        debitori_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = "w")
        debitori = []
        tip_debitori = []
       
        for i in range(2):
            debitori.append("Person %s " % str(i))
            tip_debitori.append("Person %s type" % str(i))

        for i in range(len(debitori)):
            print(debitori[i])            
       
        row_i = 4
        self.vars_debitori = []
       
       
        on_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
        off_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=48, height=24)
        on_image.put(("green",), to=(0, 0, 23,23))
        off_image.put(("red",), to=(24, 0, 47, 23))


        for i in range(len(debitori)):
            var = tk.IntVar(frame_continut, value = 0)
            interior = debitori[i] + " - " + tip_debitori[i]
            # Checkbutton(ws, image=switch_off, selectimage=switch_on, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=cb1, indicatoron=False, command=switchState)
            checkbuton = tk.Checkbutton (frame_continut, bd = 5, image = off_image, selectimage = on_image, indicatoron = False, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = var, state = tk.ACTIVE, command = lambda: self.toggle(var))
            checkbuton.grid(row = row_i, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = "nw")
            checkbuton.image = off_image
            # checkbuton.select()
            self.vars_debitori.append(var)
            row_i += 1

        self.vars_acte = []

        acte = ["Acte de Procedura", "Incheiere de Admitere", "Cerere de Incuviintare", "Instiintare Creditor"]
        for i in range(4):
            v = tk.IntVar()
            check = tk.Checkbutton(frame_acte, font = NORMAL_FONT, text = acte[i], variable = v)
            check.grid(row = row_i, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
            check.select()
            self.vars_acte.append(v)
            row_i += 1
     
        emite_acte = tk.Button(frame_acte, font = NORMAL_FONT, text = "Emite acte.", command = self.emite_acte)
        emite_acte.grid(row = row_i, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 30, ipadx = 70, ipady = 10)
        emite_acte.configure(bg = '#218838', fg = '#FFFFFF')

        buton_cancel = tk.Button(frame_acte, font = NORMAL_FONT, text = "Cancel", command = lambda: self.destroy())
        buton_cancel.grid(row = row_i, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 30, ipadx = 70, ipady = 10)
        buton_cancel.configure(bg = "red", fg = '#FFFFFF')

    def emite_acte(self):
        print(self.cal.get_date().strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
        print(self.winfo_height(), self.winfo_width())
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tk.Tk() 
        app = ConstituireDosar(root)
        app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)
        root.withdraw()
        root.mainloop()
```

I tried some options that I saw on the forum, in another file they worked fine but when I tried to implement it in the project itself the checkbutton is still unclickable and it doesn't display the images either. [tkinter checkbutton different image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559865/tkinter-checkbutton-different-image) I tried to replicate Bryan's answer, but no luck there. Also didn't receive any console error message.

Comment: you have common problem with `bug` in `PhotoImage` which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function - you have to use `self.` to assign to class variable.

Comment: we can't run it so maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Maybe when you click then it runs code but this code has wrong values and it looks like it is not clicked.

Comment: did you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you saw same options which doesn't work then you should describe them in question - so we wouldn't have to suggest these options. And you could add links to these forums. We can't run code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: you could create minimal working code with your problem which we could copy and run and see problem (and test ideas for solutions). BTW: you may have two separated problems - (1) bug in Photoimage (2) unclickable widgets - and they may need two separated solutions.

Comment: sorry for doing things wrong, first time posting here. I put a code you can check locally and updated my question, let me know if there are other things I should fix. Thanks

Comment: first use `self.` to keep `PhotoImage` in class variables - `self.on_image = ...`, `self.off_image = ...`. It should resolve first problem with not displayed images. late you may try to resolve second problem - unclickable widgets.

Comment: images are being displayed now thanks, do you have any idea on why the button is unclickable?

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal to see error messages? When I try to click `Checkbutton` then it shows error - it can't find function `toggle()`

Comment: apparently I didn't include the toggle method in the question, after removing it from the Checkbutton everything works as expected, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @furas pointed in the comments above, the problem got fixed with keeping the images as member variables of the class, also the button became clickable after removing the self.toggle(var) command from checkbutton